May Jews dress a child under the age of bar or bat mitzvah in clothing of the opposite gender
According to Halacha, may Jews  dress a child under the age of bar or bat mitzvah in clothing of the opposite gender or no? Would it be forbidden because of the mitzvah of Chinuch, and this is a prohibition of Lo Yilbash which they have a mitzvah of Chinuch in, or no?
